# MySQL: A sum from 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sum

How can I sum the columns of 3 tables?

I have table1, table2, and table3 with the column 'revenue'.

I can do `SELECT SUM(REVENUE) FROM TABLE1` but what do i do for all of them?

I tried: `SELECT SUM(
                    table1.Revenue+
                    table2.Revenue +
                    table3.Revenue
                    )
                FROM
                    table1,
                    table2,
                    table3'` but it doesn't work...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(rev) as trev
from
(
    SELECT SUM( Revenue) as rev FROM table1
    union all
    SELECT SUM( Revenue) as rev FROM table2 
    union all 
    SELECT SUM( Revenue) as rev FROM table3 
) as tmp
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add all of the individual sums together:

```
SELECT (SUM(table1.Revenue) + SUM(table2.Revenue) + SUM(table3.Revenue)) 
      AS total_rev FROM table1, table2, table3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum( revenue ) 
from (
select revenue from table1
union
select revenue from table2
union
select revenue from table3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(REVENUE) FROM (
    SELECT REVENUE FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REVENUE FROM TABLE2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REVENUE FROM TABLE3
) revenues
```